# compare list value with column names pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to compare if the values in the list is available as column names of a dataframe. If a value is missing add a new column in df. Consider I have a list and df as

lst =    ['Items', 'model', 'quantity', 'price']

```
Items model price
Phone 2023   200
xyzzy 2022   120
```

In the above scenario where the 'quantity' in the list is not available in the df and I want to add the missing as a new column in df filled with 0 like

```
Items  model quantity price
Phone  2023     0         200
xyzzy  2022     0         120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is enough:

```py
for elem in lst:
    if elem not in df.columns:
        df[elem] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#):

```
out = df.reindex(columns=lst, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   Items  model  quantity  price
0  Phone   2023         0    200
1  xyzzy   2022         0    120
```

Or add the column in place with [`Index.symmetric_difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.symmetric_difference.html):

```
df[df.columns.symmetric_difference(lst)] = 0

# or in case not all names are in lst
df[pd.Index(lst).difference(df.columns)] = 0
```

Output:

```
   Items  model  price  quantity
0  Phone   2023    200         0
1  xyzzy   2022    120         0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference in columns and then create a zero df to concatenate with the original one:

```
additional_cols = list(set(lst).difference(set(df.columns)))
        
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.DataFrame(
            np.zeros(shape=(df.shape[0], len(additional_cols))),
            columns=additional_cols
        )
    ],
    axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Items  model  price  quantity
0      1      2      4       0.0
```